# TypeScript: Get array of strings from type disjunction

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I currently have this in my codebase:

```
type Filter             =  "all"| "active"| "broken"| "disabled";
const filters: Filter[] = ["all", "active", "broken", "disabled"];
```

Can I automatically produce one from t'other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:  no.  Not at runtime at least.  And not as part of the TypeScript language.

A TypeScript `type` is there for compiler/typing purposes only.  It doesn't actually compile to anything.

You could potentially do something automated using an `enum`, as an enum actually compiles to a JavaScript object which you can pick out the properties of.  It wouldn't be based on strings like your type is...  not sure if that's super important.

```
function setupEnum(enumType: any): any[] {
    let result = [];

    for (let i in enumType)
        if (isNaN(+i))
            result.push(enumType[i]);

    return result;
}

enum Filter {
    all, active, broken, disabled
}

var filters: Filter[] = setupEnum(Filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mitch is right, this isn't currently possible.

I currently have this in my list of challenges ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16392) -> `UnionToArray`) in TS now. I think given implementation of variadic kinds (#5453 there) there may be a way to tackle this.